# MVVM where to put common logic

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, prism

I have 3 screens: Main screen with item list, an item details screen and an item update screen.

The main screen shows a list of items, each item in the list has two buttons: "Update" and "Details".

If user taps on the "Details" button, the item details screen is displayed. This screen also has an "Update" button.

Both "Update" buttons run the same (common) logic:

- display the item update screen,
- or, depending on the item state and other logic, it shows a message to user that he cannot update the item
- or, depending on other logic, display another screen

So the flow is:

```
Main (item list) screen -> Item details -> Item update
Main (item list) screen -> Item update
```

The view-models:

```
 class MainViewModel
 {
      readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
      readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

      public ICommand UpdateItemCommand { get; private set; }

      void ExecuteUpdateItem(Item item)
      {
           if(item.State == SomeState && otherLogic) 
           {
               _navigationService.NavigateTo("UpdateScreen");
           } else if(someLogic) {
               _navigationService.NavigateTo("OtherScreen");
           } else {
                // Show message to user
               _dialogService.ShowMessage(..);
           }
      }
 }

 class ItemDetailsViewModel
 {
      readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
      readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

      public ICommand UpdateItemCommand { get; private set; }

      void ExecuteUpdateItem(Item item)
      {
          // I don't want to duplicate code here
      }
 }
```

I don't know where to put the body of the `ExecuteUpdateItem` such that I am not duplicating it.

One idea I have is to have a child `ItemViewModel`:

```
 class ItemViewModel
 {
      readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
      readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

       public ICommand UpdateItemCommand { get; private set; }

      void ExecuteUpdateItem(Item item)
      {
           // put code here
      }
 }

 class MainViewModel
 {
      public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
 }

 class ItemDetailsViewModel
 {
      public ItemViewModel Item { get; private set; }
 }
```

Is there a better option?
Can I have the model do the update item instead? Can my model initiate navigation between views or display message box?

```
class Item
{
    public void UpdateItem(INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService) 
    {
          // Put code here...

    }
}
```

Or maybe have an `ItemService` which does this?

The view-models get the INavigationService and IDialogService by dependency injection.
If I add an `ItemService` I'd have to pass the two services from view-model to the `ItemService` service.

Comment: A common service seems like the right answer tot me.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks. An `ItemService` you mean?

Comment: Yes, that seems like a good name

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Please see the new paragraph at the end of the question

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect; you would inject the `ItemService` which would take `INavigationService` and `IDialogService` as dependencies. The container should populate it for you.

Comment: `IDialogService` yes, but not `INavigationService`. If you know how Prism works, the navigation service is injected in view-models (I am using Prism for Xamarin Forms)

Comment: Then you may have to pass that manually to the method. I'm not familiar enough with Prism to know if there is a better solution.